# Tensorflow CSV Dataset not utilizing GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset composed of several csv files. I am reading the data using tensorflow dataset API:

```
my_ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern="gs://folder/*.csv",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    column_names=columns,
    column_defaults=column_types,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,
    label_name="target")
```

so when I am training the model using strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() on two GPUs the usage of the GPUs is not more than 1%. But when I read the same dataset entirely on memory and using same strategy the usage ramps up to ~30 % in both GPUs, so not sure if something else is required to use GPUs more efficiently.

Thanks!

I tried several options with the dataset to see if that helps to utilize the GPU better, but nothing works

Comment: Are you using the same batch size?

Comment: I tested with same batch size and increasing it. In both cases the GPU utilization is small for dataset api